# Счетчик запросов файла

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Нужно отследить сколько раз отбращались к фалу на сервере.
в .htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ index.php?file=$1
```

в скрипте

```js
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
  $file = 'status.txt';
  file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($file) + 1);
}
```

количество запросов изменяется,но сам файл в том же браузере не отображается-как профиксить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо отдать файл картинки пользователю через php после увеличения счетчика. Для этого можно использовать функцию readfile() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php
Пример с официальной страницы:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Заголовки высылаете по своему усмотрению. Можете оставить только `'Content-type: image/png'`

Answer (score 1):

Вы в .htaccess явно меняете выдачу png на php-скрипт. Что-бы показать картинку, вам надо в скрипте сделать вывод картинки (используем GD):

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
 $file = 'status.txt';
 file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($file) + 1);

 $image = "/some/path/to/images/".$_GET['file'];
 $im = imagecreatefrompng($image);
 header('Content-Type: image/png');
 imagepng($im);
 imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Comment: ни черта это не выводит)))

Comment: @DarkVss: 1. php-gd установлен? 
2. `echo $image` - можете показать?

Comment: честно говоря,мне уже по барабану метод @Visman работает-мне этого достаточно,это нужно только для чека прочитанности мыла.Кстати ваш способ "ходит по кругу",когда выводит картинку в браузер-он её запрашивает на сервере)) хотя может я не понимаю правильно-но факт что ничего не выводиться)